# How to get value of toggle type checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, checkbox

I am using a toggle switch checkbox. I want to get the value of this switch when its state is changed using javascript or jQuery.

According to that value I want to highlight the text of `label` i.e. `option1` or `option2` used with the toggle switch.

Can someone help me to resolve this problem?

```css
.checkbox.checbox-switch {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.checkbox.checbox-switch label,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.checkbox.checbox-switch label input,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch input {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox.checbox-switch label span,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch span {
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  background-color: gray;
  border-color: gray;
  box-shadow: rgb(223, 223, 223) 0px 0px 0px 0px inset;
  transition: border 0.4s ease 0s, box-shadow 0.4s ease 0s;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.checkbox.checbox-switch label span:before,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch span:before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  content: " ";
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  top: -2px;
}

.checkbox.checbox-switch label>input:checked+span:before,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch>input:checked+span:before {
  left: 16px;
  top: -2px;
}


/* Switch Primary */

.checkbox.checbox-switch.switch-primary label>input:checked+span,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch.switch-primary>input:checked+span {
  background-color: rgb(103, 209, 224);
  border-color: rgb(103, 209, 224);
  /*box-shadow: rgb(0, 105, 217) 0px 0px 0px 8px inset;*/
  transition: border 0.4s ease 0s, box-shadow 0.4s ease 0s, background-color 1.2s ease 0s;
}

.checkbox.checbox-switch.switch-primary label>input:checked:disabled+span,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch.switch-primary>input:checked:disabled+span {
  background-color: gray;
  border-color: gray;
  /* box-shadow: rgb(109, 163, 221) 0px 0px 0px 8px inset;*/
  transition: border 0.4s ease 0s, box-shadow 0.4s ease 0s, background-color 1.2s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox checbox-switch switch-primary">
  <label id="option1" for="switch1">Option1</label>&nbsp;
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="" checked="" id="switch1" />
    <span></span>
  </label>
  <label id="option2" for="switch1">Option2</label>
</div>
```

Comment: This will help: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/BaQLmWq

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an event listener:

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener
>
> The EventTarget method `addEventListener()` sets up a function that will be called whenever the specified event is delivered to the target. Common targets are Element, Document, and Window, but the target may be any object that supports events (such as XMLHttpRequest).
>
> `addEventListener()` works by adding a function or an object that implements [EventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventListener) to the list of event listeners for the specified event type on the [EventTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget) on which it's called.

example

```js
let test = document.querySelector('#switch1');

test.addEventListener('change', function() { 
  if (this.checked == true) {
    console.log('true');// do here what you need instead
  } else {
    console.log('false')// do here what you need instead
  }
 
})
```

```css
.checkbox.checbox-switch {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.checkbox.checbox-switch label,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.checkbox.checbox-switch label input,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch input {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox.checbox-switch label span,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch span {
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  background-color: gray;
  border-color: gray;
  box-shadow: rgb(223, 223, 223) 0px 0px 0px 0px inset;
  transition: border 0.4s ease 0s, box-shadow 0.4s ease 0s;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.checkbox.checbox-switch label span:before,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch span:before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  content: " ";
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  top: -2px;
}

.checkbox.checbox-switch label>input:checked+span:before,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch>input:checked+span:before {
  left: 16px;
  top: -2px;
}


/* Switch Primary */

.checkbox.checbox-switch.switch-primary label>input:checked+span,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch.switch-primary>input:checked+span {
  background-color: rgb(103, 209, 224);
  border-color: rgb(103, 209, 224);
  /*box-shadow: rgb(0, 105, 217) 0px 0px 0px 8px inset;*/
  transition: border 0.4s ease 0s, box-shadow 0.4s ease 0s, background-color 1.2s ease 0s;
}

.checkbox.checbox-switch.switch-primary label>input:checked:disabled+span,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch.switch-primary>input:checked:disabled+span {
  background-color: gray;
  border-color: gray;
  /* box-shadow: rgb(109, 163, 221) 0px 0px 0px 8px inset;*/
  transition: border 0.4s ease 0s, box-shadow 0.4s ease 0s, background-color 1.2s ease 0s;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox checbox-switch switch-primary">
  <label id="option1" for="switch1">Option1</label>&nbsp;
  <label>
                          <input type="checkbox" name="" checked="" id="switch1"/>
                          <span></span>
                      </label>
  <label id="option2" for="switch1">Option2</label>
</div>
```

edit for futur readers, a working example toggling a class

```js
let test = document.querySelector('#switch1');

test.addEventListener('change', function() {
  if (this.checked == true) {
    console.log('true'); // do here what you need instead 
    switchTest()
  } else {
    console.log('false') // do here what you need instead 
    switchTest()
  }

})

function switchTest() {
  let options = document.querySelectorAll('label[id^=option]');
  for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    options[i].classList.toggle('highlight');
  }
}
```

```css
.checkbox.checbox-switch {
  padding-left: 0;
}

.checkbox.checbox-switch label,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 0;
}

.checkbox.checbox-switch label input,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch input {
  display: none;
}

.checkbox.checbox-switch label span,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch span {
  width: 35px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 18px;
  border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  background-color: gray;
  border-color: gray;
  box-shadow: rgb(223, 223, 223) 0px 0px 0px 0px inset;
  transition: border 0.4s ease 0s, box-shadow 0.4s ease 0s;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.checkbox.checbox-switch label span:before,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch span:before {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  content: " ";
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  left: 0px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  top: -2px;
}

.checkbox.checbox-switch label>input:checked+span:before,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch>input:checked+span:before {
  left: 16px;
  top: -2px;
}


/* Switch Primary */

.checkbox.checbox-switch.switch-primary label>input:checked+span,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch.switch-primary>input:checked+span {
  background-color: rgb(103, 209, 224);
  border-color: rgb(103, 209, 224);
  /*box-shadow: rgb(0, 105, 217) 0px 0px 0px 8px inset;*/
  transition: border 0.4s ease 0s, box-shadow 0.4s ease 0s, background-color 1.2s ease 0s;
}

.checkbox.checbox-switch.switch-primary label>input:checked:disabled+span,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch.switch-primary>input:checked:disabled+span {
  background-color: gray;
  border-color: gray;
  /* box-shadow: rgb(109, 163, 221) 0px 0px 0px 8px inset;*/
  transition: border 0.4s ease 0s, box-shadow 0.4s ease 0s, background-color 1.2s ease 0s;
}

.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="checkbox checbox-switch switch-primary">
  <label id="option1" class="highlight" for="switch1">Option1</label>&nbsp;
  <label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="" checked="" id="switch1"/>
    <span></span>
</label>
  <label id="option2" for="switch1">Option2</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Tell if its what you want :)

```js
$('.checbox-switch label#option1, .checbox-switch label#option2').click(function() {
  var getID = $(this).attr('id');
  $('.checbox-switch label').removeClass('selected');
  $(this).addClass('selected');
  console.log(getID);
})
```

```css
.checkbox.checbox-switch {
    padding-left: 0;
}

.checkbox.checbox-switch label,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 0;
}
.checkbox.checbox-switch label input,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch input {
    display: none;
}
.checkbox.checbox-switch label span,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch span {
    width: 35px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    height: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
    background-color: gray;
    border-color: gray;
    box-shadow: rgb(223, 223, 223) 0px 0px 0px 0px inset;
    transition: border 0.4s ease 0s, box-shadow 0.4s ease 0s;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 5px;
}
.checkbox.checbox-switch label span:before,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch span:before {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    content: " ";
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
    left: 0px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
    top:-2px;
}
.checkbox.checbox-switch label > input:checked + span:before,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch > input:checked + span:before {
    left: 16px;top:-2px;
}

/* Switch Primary */
.checkbox.checbox-switch.switch-primary label > input:checked + span,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch.switch-primary > input:checked + span {
    background-color: rgb(103, 209, 224);
    border-color: rgb(103, 209, 224);
    /*box-shadow: rgb(0, 105, 217) 0px 0px 0px 8px inset;*/
    transition: border 0.4s ease 0s, box-shadow 0.4s ease 0s, background-color 1.2s ease 0s;
}
.checkbox.checbox-switch.switch-primary label > input:checked:disabled + span,
.checkbox-inline.checbox-switch.switch-primary > input:checked:disabled + span {
    background-color: gray;
    border-color: gray;
   /* box-shadow: rgb(109, 163, 221) 0px 0px 0px 8px inset;*/
    transition: border 0.4s ease 0s, box-shadow 0.4s ease 0s, background-color 1.2s ease 0s;
}
.selected { border-bottom:1px solid cyan; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="checkbox checbox-switch switch-primary">
     <label id="option1"for="switch1">Option1</label>&nbsp;
      <label>
          <input type="checkbox" name="" checked="" id="switch1"/>
          <span></span>
      </label>
     <label id="option2" for="switch1">Option2</label>     
</div>
```